# Firebase Realtime Database and HTTP requests: complex queries over multiple axes

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code to retrieve data with timestamps within the given dates and hour ranges:

```
app.get('/mymeals/filtered', async(req,res) => {
    let dayFrom= req.query.dayFrom;
    let dayTo= req.query.dayTo;
    let hourFrom= req.query.hourFrom;
    let hourTo= req.query.hourTo;
    console.log(`${dayFrom}-${dayTo} ${hourFrom} ${hourTo}`);
    let userId= req.user.uid;
    return await dbroot.ref(`duplicates/${userId}`)
        .orderByKey().startAt(`${dayFrom}`).endAt(`${dayTo}`).once('value').then( (snapshot) => {
            console.log(snapshot.val());
            return snapshot.ref.orderByKey().startAt(`${hourFrom}`).endAt(`${hourTo}`).once('value').then( (s) => {
                console.log(s.val());
                return res.status(200).send(s.val());
            });
        })
});
```

The database in question looks like follows:
[image]

That is, for easy retrieval, I first bucket the items by date, then within the date -- by hour. So, `12` in the above image is `12:00PM`.
Now, Firebase does not allow chaining two `orderByKey()`s, that is why I am trying to query first by date, and then, given a snapshot, trying to iterate over the children using `snapshot.forEach(child)`, like so:

```
    app.get('/mymeals/filtered', async(req,res) => {
    let dayFrom= req.query.dayFrom;
    let dayTo= req.query.dayTo;
    let hourFrom= req.query.hourFrom;
    let hourTo= req.query.hourTo;
    console.log(`${dayFrom}-${dayTo} ${hourFrom} ${hourTo}`);
    let userId= req.user.uid;
    return await dbroot.ref(`duplicates/${userId}`)
        .orderByKey().startAt(`${dayFrom}`).endAt(`${dayTo}`).once('value').then( (snapshot) => {
            console.log(snapshot.val());
            acc= [];
            snapshot.forEach( (day) => {
                day.forEach((hour) => {
                    console.log("This: " + hour.key);
                    if (hourFrom <= hour.key && hour.key <= hourTo)
                        hour.forEach((meal) => {
                            acc.push(meal.val());
                        });
                });
            });
            return res.status(200).send(acc);
        })
});
```

My question is, it is still possible to somehow chain the queries along the two axes, or an approach similar to the second code snippet is the only way to go?

Comment: There are two possible meanings here. Do you want meals from `dayFrom` at `hourFrom` until `dayTo` at `hourTo`? Or do you want meals on for each day from `dayFrom` until `dayTo`, between `hourFrom` and `hourTo`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: The second code snippet gets the job done, and indeed it is the second meaning -- the so-called "orthogonal range reporting", in CS parlance.

Comment: That looks like it's the second option from my first comment. There is no way to query two properties in a single query, and from a quick scan it seems like you also can't combine these with a single synthetic property. It looks like you'll need a query for each day at least, unless there are limits that you didn't share (e.g. the time ranges are a fixed, limited number). Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: Now I see I indeed used the approach "filter first at server, and the rest at client" approach in my Android code, first binding to a query and additionally filtering in `onChildAdded` method. As for this question, I am using the second snippet, then.